# Realm. Sync initial data from big database

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'll have to sync database with 200000 row between devices.

Each existing and new row will have to be sync on all devices.

### 2 questions:

- On Realm, will I be able to get all my 200000 row in the initial sync(or is there a limitation?
- On Realm, can I have the initial 200000 ros directly in app, so only the new\updated one will be synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

- All rows will be synchronized regardless of how many you have, but be aware that a single transaction adding 200,000 objects may consume an unexpected amount of space on the device. We recommend measuring to see if this is within your acceptable range, and if not, split the creation of the objects into multiple, smaller transactions.
- Unfortunately, ROS does not yet support prepackaging a synchronized Realm file. We are aware of this use case, but we don't have a timeline for it at this point. So far, use cases where the initial sync was unacceptable have been fairly rare.

Comment: By the time I have you.
If my database was created\filled, may I add the lines below to my model and get the index created, of should this need to be done before the database was created?  (in other work, can I create an index after the database was created?)
+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties {
  return @[@"title"];
}

Comment: Yes, it should be fine to add an index after the database was created. Contrast this with primary keys, which must be established before any objects are created. I hope that answers your question.